# X axis for plt plot python is cluttered together

Tags: python, matplotlib, linechart

```
plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
aapl_data.plot.line(x='Date',y='Adj Close',title='test')
plt.ylabel('Adj Close')plt.show()
```

[image]

How do i declutter the X axis. I tried using figsize in the code but it does not do anything

Answer (score 1):

Better show the whole code. Since I'm not sure if you have such a string: `ax = plt.axes()`

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval = 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to formate the date

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two solutions to this problem.

1. Increasing the width of the window. This can be achieved by:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40,4))
fig.add_subplot(1,1,1).plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

2. Making the labels vertical rather than horizontal. This can be done by:

```
plt.xticks(range(10), rotation='vertical')
```

Comment: I tried method 1 but there is no difference to it

Comment: @ColinGiam I have edited the code and added a sample code for reference.